# Symbol lookup error when running Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, undefined-symbol

When I close my eclipse,an error dialog pops up,and gives the belowing error information:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/opt/java/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-jar /usr/share/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /usr/share/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/share/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /usr/share/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 578003
-vm /opt/java/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-jar /usr/share/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

And in the gnome-terminal a symbol lookup error occurs:

```
/opt/java/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-xim.so: undefined symbol: gtk_im_context_get_type
```

I've searched Google and didn't get much information about this error.
Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: I notice that the error only occur when I type a dot(.) to autocomplete a function name of a class.